# Create Customer Objects and Properties in an Array

Tags: powershell

Thank you for your help in advance.

What i need to do is to add Multiple properties and sub-properties in an array of objects.

To be specific, i am using PowerNSX to get some data of the NSX Cluster prepared for NSX, this is acomplished by using the Command Get-NsxClusterStatus, the return value of this command will be something like the below:

```
featureId          : com.vmware.vshield.firewall
featureVersion     : 5.5
updateAvailable    : false
status             : GREEN
message            : 
installed          : true
enabled            : true
allowConfiguration : false

featureId          : com.vmware.vshield.vsm.messagingInfra
updateAvailable    : false
status             : GREEN
installed          : true
enabled            : true
allowConfiguration : false

featureId          : com.vmware.vshield.vsm.vdr_mon
featureVersion     : 5.5
updateAvailable    : false
status             : UNKNOWN
installed          : false
enabled            : true
allowConfiguration : false

featureId          : com.vmware.vshield.vsm.vxlan
featureVersion     : 5.5
updateAvailable    : false
status             : GREEN
installed          : true
enabled            : true
allowConfiguration : false

featureId          : com.vmware.vshield.vsm.nwfabric.hostPrep
featureVersion     : 6.3.4.7087695
updateAvailable    : false
status             : GREEN
installed          : true
enabled            : true
allowConfiguration : false
```

If i used the Get-NsxClusterStatus command in a foreach loop to get all the info for all the Cluster then and add them to an array, i will have multiple output from the above, As an example:

```
$AllClusters = Get-Cluster 
$AllNsxClusterInfo = @()
foreach ($Cluster in $AllClusters) {
$NsxClustersInfo = $Cluster | Get-NsxClusterStatus
$AllNsxClusterInfo += $NsxClustersInfo
}
```

The output of the $AllNsxClusterInfo will be the same as the above example but multiple time one for each cluster.

What i need is to have a foreach loop and add within the $AllNsxClusterInfo array a property for each cluster and in this property i will have another 4 properties as follow (firewall, messagingInfra, vxlan, hostPrep) and in each of these 4 properties i will have the required data

The idea is to organize the returned value for future use in the script i am creating.

at the moment what i am doing (Which is failing) is as follow:

```
$GetAllClusters = Get-Cluster
$PreparedClusters = @()
$PreparedClusterInfo = @()
$i = 1
$Cluster = Get-Cluster -Name HQ-Prod
$CheckClusterPreparation = $Cluster | Get-NsxClusterStatus | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.nwfabric.hostPrep"}
$ClusterName = $Cluster.name
If ($CheckClusterPreparation.installed -Match "True") {$PreparedClusters += $Cluster.name}
$GetPreparedClusterInfo = $Cluster | Get-NsxClusterStatus

$ClsuterNumber = "ClusterNumber" + $i

$PreparedClusterInfo += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ClusterNumber=$ClsuterNumber}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Feature="hostPrep"}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName.hostPrep += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Value=($GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.nwfabric.hostPrep"})}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Feature="vxlan"}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName.vxlan += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Value=($GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.vxlan"})}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Feature="firewall"}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName.firewall += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Value=($GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.firewall"})}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Feature="messagingInfra"}
$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterName.messagingInfra += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Value=($GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.messagingInfra"})}
```

What i need at the end it when i want to retrive the VXLAN info of cluster number 2 i would use the following:

$PreparedClusterInfo.ClusterNumber2.vxlan

Hope i was able to explain my self clearly and thank you for your help

Comment: Why would you want to do that instead of using an array or a hashtable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you misunderstand how to construct a PSObject, and I think that you need to know what hashtables are.

Constructing a PSObject (or [PSCustomObject] using the type accelerator). You construct an object to have various properties (which you name), and can assign values for those properties. Take the first object that you create as an example:

```
$PreparedClusterInfo += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ClusterNumber=$ClsuterNumber}
```

This creates an object using the hashtable `@{ClusterNumber=$ClsuterNumber}` to define the properties and their values. That hashtable has 1 key/value combination, so the object will have one property. That property will be named 'ClusterNumber', and will have a value of `$ClsuterNumber` (which I'm guessing is a typo for `$ClusterNumber`, and will use that going forward).

You could reference that object and see:

```
ClusterNumber: ClusterNumber1
```

...since 'ClusterNumber1' was the value of `$ClusterNumber` when the object was created. You then proceed to create more and more objects.

I think what would serve you better here is a hashtable. A hashtable, in simple terms, is a reference dictionary. You define keys (on the left), and the value for that key (on the right). Then when you reference the key later it will tell you the value. Such as:

```
$MyHashTable = @{
    'Animal' = 'Dog'
    'Food' = 'Cake'
    'Vehicle' = 'HD Fatboy'
}
```

I defined the keys for that hashtable as Animal, Food, and Vehicle. I can then reference those later to get their value, such as `$MyHashTable.Food` will return `Cake`. Another way to do this is to create an empty hashtable, and then add Key/Value pairs to it as such:

```
$MyHashTable = @{}
$MyHashTable.Add('Animal','Dog')
$MyHashTable.Add('Food','Cake')
$MyHashTable.Add('Vehicle','HD Fatboy')
```

Or you could even do it this way:

```
$MyHashTable = @{}
$MyHashTable.'Animal' = 'Dog'
$MyHashTable.'Food' = 'Cake'
$MyHashTable.'Vehicle' = 'HD Fatboy'
```

For your purposes I would make a hashtable where the cluster numbers are the keys, and the value is a nested hashtable where you can define your various other properties such as 'vxlan'.

```
$PreparedClusterInfo = @{}

<Other code to collect cluster info>

$PreparedClusterInfo.$ClusterNumber = @{
    hostPrep = $GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.nwfabric.hostPrep"}
    vxlan = $GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.vxlan"}
    firewall = $GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.firewall"}
    messagingInfra = $GetPreparedClusterInfo | Where-Object {$_.featureId -Match "com.vmware.vshield.vsm.messagingInfra"}
}
```

You then repeat this for your other clusters once you have redefined `$ClusterNumber` and `$GetPreparedClusterInfo`.

At this point you can indeed reference `$PreparedClusterInfo` like you want to be able to and it will return the value you expect:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PreparedClusterInfo.ClusterNumber2.vxlan

featureId          : com.vmware.vshield.vsm.vxlan
featureVersion     : 5.5
updateAvailable    : false
status             : GREEN
installed          : true
enabled            : true
allowConfiguration : false
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, this not only helped me with what i need but it also explained something to me that i did not know, Apologies as i am new for SCripting and Powershell,

The hashtables defiantly helped me and i was able to get what i need.

Thank you so much.